Sampling from a specific variant in a mc2d mcnode data frame in R
I am trying to sample from a specific variant in a mcnode - the data frame produced by the 2 dimensional monte carlo package mc2d. I have copied what the mcnode looks like below.
Any ideas how to sample from a specific variate or pull all of the data from only one variate?
mcnode:
node    mode  nsv  nsu nva variate   min mean median   max Nas type outm
1    x numeric 1000 1000   8       1 34.44 8427   1739 60520   0   VU each
2    x numeric 1000 1000   8       2 11.23 3983    761 47447   0   VU each
3    x numeric 1000 1000   8       3  6.24 2349    443 33426   0   VU each
4    x numeric 1000 1000   8       4  4.23 1585    307 22715   0   VU each
5    x numeric 1000 1000   8       5  3.17 1163    233 15820   0   VU each
6    x numeric 1000 1000   8       6  2.51  904    183 11448   0   VU each
7    x numeric 1000 1000   8       7  2.03  731    147  8595   0   VU each
8    x numeric 1000 1000   8       8  1.65  609    123  6802   0   VU each

I am able to randomly sample from all of the means using sample (sample(dose_2t19_CF8, size = 1), but I can't select the variate. I can't figure out how the mcnode data frame is set up, and when I try to force it into another format I can either get a summary table or I can use unmc and end up with a list of values, but I loose the variate. I can use (which = ) as part of a plotting command to choose a particular variate, but not when trying to sample or use unmc to pull the data for only one variate.
Understanding how the mc2d package/mcnode data is structured would help me to subset the data I am trying to. Or potentially someone else has already written a script or package for this, that would be very helpful.
